# Is Tipsi-Stripe just for creating Stripe tokens or can you use it for the actual transactions?

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe into my react native app to enable credit card usage, but I've become a little confused. Through my research I have gathered that stripe requires a token consisting of the card information to complete a transaction, and it seems that the way to do this on react native is by using Tipsi-Stripe. Tipsi does not have very thorough documentation so its hard to tell what its total purpose is. Their given project example seems to show that you can only create tokens through it unless using apple or android pay, but I feel like I am just missing something. Other tutorials mention use of a backend to make it work but the Tipsi documentation says nothing of a backend. So is Tipsi able to complete transactions without android and apple pay? I feel i have a fundamental misunderstanding of Stripe with rwact native and the limited documentation on using the two together is making it pretty hard to figure out. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks

Comment: you send the token to back-end and then back-end is used for transactions.

Comment: Is a backend absolutely required @haider ali

Comment: "Stripe has created a Java library for Android, allowing you to easily submit payments from an Android app. With our mobile library, we shoulder the burden of PCI compliance by eliminating the need to send card data directly to your server. Instead, our libraries send the card data directly to our servers, where we can convert them to tokens.

Your app will receive the token back, and can then send the token to an endpoint on your server, where it can be used to process a payment, establish recurring billing, or merely saved for later use."
https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android

Comment: @haider ali ok i get that there are tokens, but in their documentation for react-native (not android) they suggest you use tipsi-stripe for making charges (not tokens) but creating charges is not mentioned anywhere in the tipsi documentation, only creating tokens, do you see where my confusion is coming from?

Comment: Sure, the confusion is understandable, but you do have to set up a backend server to actually make the charges. This is because these types of requests require a secret key and this could be extracted or compromised from your native app, thus rendering your entire account vulnerable to exploitation.